# I'm trying to get localisation in multidimensional array which is equal to mouse coord and put the tile id on it but array refresh everytime

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, game-development, tiled

I'm new to dev and i'm trying to learn JS doing game on canvas.

This is a Tile Map Editor project

I'm looking to create a multidimensional array with the ID's of the tiles i drew in the canvas. So when i go to export the JSON i can handle the colissions easily on my game.

But I'm stuck, I can detect the mouse position and put my tile id in the right place, but I don't know how to save the information in my array. Every time i try the array does not save the tile id and replaces with the new one.

```
  //////////////////////////////
 //// TO RESOLVE !!!!! ///////
////////////////////////////
let array = [];

function saveIdexedTiledMap() {
   for (let l = 0; l < canvas.height / 32; l++) {
      array[l] = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < canvas.width / 32; c++) {
      array[l][c] = 0;
    }
  }
  array[mouseCanvasGrids.y / 32][mouseCanvasGrids.x / 32] =
    selectedTile[0].index;

  console.log(array);
}
```

Thanks :D

```js
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// GET INPUT VALUES AND BUTTONS //////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const clearCanvas = document.querySelector("#btn-clearCanvas");
        const exportImage = document.querySelector("#btn-exportImage");

        const form = document.querySelector("#form");
        const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

        const elems = Array.from(form.elements);

        submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          elems.forEach((el) => localStorage.setItem(`${el.id}`, `${el.value}`));
        });

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// GET BOTH CANVAS AND VARIABLES //////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const canvasImg = document.querySelector("#canvasImg");
        const ctxImg = canvasImg.getContext("2d");

        let gridsPosX;
        let gridsPosY;

        let tileSizeW = 32;
        let tileSizeH = 32;

        let gridsColor = "#bad1f5";

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// DRAW ON CANVAS TILE GRIDS //////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        class DrawGrids {
          constructor(x, y, canvasW, canvasH, tileW, tileH, color) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.canvasW = canvasW;
            this.canvasH = canvasH;
            this.tileSizeW = tileW;
            this.tileSizeH = tileH;
            this.color = color;
          }

          draw() {
            let tileGridsX;
            let tileGridsY;

            for (let l = 0; l < this.canvasH / this.tileSizeH; l++) {
              for (let c = 0; c < this.canvasW / this.tileSizeW; c++) {
                tileGridsX = c * this.tileSizeW;
                tileGridsY = l * this.tileSizeH;

                const variables = [ctx, ctxImg];

                variables.forEach((el) => {
                  el.strokeStyle = this.color;
                  el.rect(tileGridsX, tileGridsY, this.tileSizeH, this.tileSizeW);
                  el.stroke();
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }

        const canvasImgGrids = new DrawGrids(
          gridsPosX,
          gridsPosY,
          canvasImg.width,
          canvasImg.height,
          tileSizeW,
          tileSizeH,
          gridsColor
        );

        const canvasMapGrids = new DrawGrids(
          gridsPosX,
          gridsPosY,
          canvas.width,
          canvas.height,
          tileSizeW,
          tileSizeH,
          gridsColor
        );

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// GET/SHOW FILE AND CUT IMAGE INTO ARRAY//////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const tileImage = new Image();
        tileImage.src = "./images/tileset_32x32(new).png";
        tileImage.onload = cutImage;

        let imageTileParts = [];

        function cutImage() {
          let index = 1;
          for (let l = 0; l < tileImage.height / 32; l++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < tileImage.width / 32; c++) {
              imageTileParts.push({
                index,
                tileImage,
                x: c * tileSizeW,
                y: l * tileSizeH,
                w: tileSizeW,
                h: tileSizeH,
                x_draw: c * tileSizeW,
                y_draw: l * tileSizeH,
              });
              index++;
            }
          }
          showSpreadSheetImg();
        }

        function showSpreadSheetImg() {
          imageTileParts.forEach((el) => {
            ctxImg.drawImage(
              el.tileImage,
              el.x,
              el.y,
              el.w,
              el.h,
              el.x_draw,
              el.y_draw,
              el.w,
              el.h
            );
          });

          canvasImgGrids.draw();
          canvasMapGrids.draw();

          getMouseCanvasImgPos();
          getMouseCanvasPos();
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// GET MOUSE POSITION AND EVENT CLICK //////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        let mouseCanvasImg = {};
        let mouseCanvasGrids = {};

        function getMouseCanvasImgPos() {
          const canvasImgPos = canvasImg.getBoundingClientRect();
          canvasImg.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            mouseCanvasImg = {
              x: Math.floor((e.clientX - canvasImgPos.left) / tileSizeW) * tileSizeW,
              y: Math.floor((e.clientY - canvasImgPos.top) / tileSizeH) * tileSizeH,
            };
            compareMouseIdWithTiles();
          });
        }

        function getMouseCanvasPos() {
          const canvasGridsPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            mouseCanvasGrids = {
              x: Math.floor((e.clientX - canvasGridsPos.left) / tileSizeW) * tileSizeW,
              y: Math.floor((e.clientY - canvasGridsPos.top) / tileSizeH) * tileSizeH,
            };

            if (e.button == 0) {
              drawSelectedTileInGrids();
            } else if (e.button == 2) {
              deleteSelectedTile();
            }

            saveIdexedTiledMap();
          });
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// COMPARE MOUSE WITH TILES POSITION //////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        let selectedTile = [];

        function compareMouseIdWithTiles() {
          for (let i = 0; i < imageTileParts.length; i++) {
            if (
              mouseCanvasImg.x == imageTileParts[i].x &&
              mouseCanvasImg.y == imageTileParts[i].y
            ) {
              // Delete last tile clicked in the array
              if (selectedTile.length >= 1) {
                selectedTile.shift();
              }

              selectedTile.push(imageTileParts[i]);
            }
          }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// DRAW/DELETE SELECTED TILE IN GRIDS ///////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // :: DRAW :: //
        function drawSelectedTileInGrids() {
          if (selectedTile <= 0) {
            console.log("Veuillez choisir une Tile !!!");
          } else {
            ctx.drawImage(
              selectedTile[0].tileImage,
              selectedTile[0].x,
              selectedTile[0].y,
              selectedTile[0].w,
              selectedTile[0].h,
              mouseCanvasGrids.x,
              mouseCanvasGrids.y,
              tileSizeW,
              tileSizeH
            );
          }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////
        //// TO RESOLVE ON !!!!! ////
        ////////////////////////////
        let array = [];

        function saveIdexedTiledMap() {
          for (let l = 0; l < canvas.height / 32; l++) {
            array[l] = [];
            for (let c = 0; c < canvas.width / 32; c++) {
              array[l][c] = 0;
            }
          }
          array[mouseCanvasGrids.y / 32][mouseCanvasGrids.x / 32] =
            selectedTile[0].index;

          console.log(array);
        }

        // :: DELETE :: //
        function deleteSelectedTile() {
          ctx.clearRect(mouseCanvasGrids.x, mouseCanvasGrids.y, tileSizeW, tileSizeH);
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// CLEAR/SAVE CANVAS IMAGE ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////

        clearCanvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          canvasMapGrids.draw();
        });

        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// EXPORT CANVAS IMAGE ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////
```

```css
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
          margin: 0;
          margin-bottom: 50px;
          padding: 0;
        }

        .body {
          width: 900px;
          margin-bottom: 50px;
          background-color: #ccdaf0;
          margin: 20px auto;
          border-radius: 8px;
          background: linear-gradient(145deg, #dae9ff, #b8c4d8);
          box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px #818997, -7px -7px 12px #ffffff;
        }

        header {
          margin: 0 30px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: baseline;
        }

        .content {
          display: flex;
        }

        aside {
          flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .canvas-content {
          margin: 0 30px;
          border-radius: 8px;
          background: #ccdaf0;
          box-shadow: inset 7px 7px 12px #818997, inset -7px -7px 12px #ffffff;
        }

        .img-container {
          padding: 10px;
          height: 200px;
        }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <title>Tile Map Editor</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="body">
              <header>
                <h1>Tile Map Editor</h1>
                <div>
                  <button id="btn-clearCanvas">clear canvas</button>
                  <button id="btn-exportImage">Export Map</button>
                </div>
              </header>

              <div class="content">
                <aside>
                  <form id="form">
                    <label>Config : </label>
                    <div class="config-container">
                      <div class="mapSize">
                        <label>Map Size : </label>
                        <label>width</label>
                        <input type="number" id="mapSizeW" />
                        <label>height</label>
                        <input type="number" id="mapSizeH" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="tileSize">
                        <label>Tile Size</label>
                        <input type="number" id="tileSize" />
                      </div>
                      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Valider" />
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </aside>

                <div class="canvas-content">
                  <canvas
                    oncontextmenu="return false;"
                    width="608"
                    height="416"
                  ></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="img-container">
                <canvas
                  oncontextmenu="return false;"
                  id="canvasImg"
                  width="600"
                  height="200"
                ></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./index.js"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mistake is in this function, you are clearing the array on every save:

```js
let array = [];

function saveIdexedTiledMap() {
   for (let l = 0; l < canvas.height / 32; l++) {
      array[l] = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < canvas.width / 32; c++) {
      array[l][c] = 0;
    }
  }
  array[mouseCanvasGrids.y / 32][mouseCanvasGrids.x / 32] =
    selectedTile[0].index;

  console.log(array);
}
```

So you need to move the clearing outside like this:

```js
let array = [];

for (let l = 0; l < canvas.height / 32; l++) {
  array[l] = [];
  for (let c = 0; c < canvas.width / 32; c++) {
    array[l][c] = 0;
  }
}

function saveIdexedTiledMap() {
  array[mouseCanvasGrids.y / 32][mouseCanvasGrids.x / 32] =
    selectedTile[0].index;

  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks @Andrei. I'm so disgusted that I wasted a long time trying to do this...